# Scaling an Image/Rectangle in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Is it possible to "scale" a rectangle inside of pygame. Kinda like when you scale your windows on your desktop, I'm wondering how you could do so in pygame. Your cursor will control the size of the rectangle.

I used skrx method and I tried to do it for 2 rectangles:

```
if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if winVirus.collidepoint(evnt.pos):
            rectVSelect = True
        elif winCrime.collidepoint(evnt.pos):
            rectCSelect = True
    elif evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        rectVSelect = False
        rectCSelect = False
    if evnt.type == MOUSEMOTION:
        if rectVSelect:
            winVirus.w += evnt.rel[0]
            winVirus.h += evnt.rel[1]
            winVirus.w = max(winVirus.w, 50)
            winVirus.h = max(winVirus.h, 50)  
        elif rectCSelect:
            winCrime.w += evnt.rel[0]
            winCrime.h += evnt.rel[1]
            winCrime.w = max(winVirus.w, 50)
            winCrime.h = max(winVirus.h, 50)
```

but for the second rectangle, it would move properly there seems to be a problem with "winCrime". winVirus" works perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean? Scale a rectangle inside a pygame window?

Comment: yea like when your on your computer, you can scale the size of the windows. I want to know how to scale the size of a rectangle which is with your mouse inside of pygame window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply change the width and the height of the rect (the `w` and `h` attributes). When the mouse gets moved (a `MOUSEMOTION` event is added to the queue) and if the rect is selected, add the relative movement `event.rel` to the width and the height.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
rect = pg.Rect(100, 100, 161, 100)
rect_selected = False

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set rect_selected to True when the user clicks on the rect.
            if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                rect_selected = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            rect_selected = False
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if rect_selected:
                # Simply adjust the width and the height of the screen
                # by subtracting the relative mouse movement.
                rect.w += event.rel[0]
                rect.h += event.rel[1]
                # 10*10 px is the minimal size, so that the rect can
                # still be clicked.
                rect.w = max(rect.w, 10)
                rect.h = max(rect.h, 10)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 100, 250), rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

---

If you want to do this with several rects, you can just assign the clicked rect to a variable (`selected_rect` in this case) and then scale it.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
rect1 = pg.Rect(100, 100, 161, 100)
rect2 = pg.Rect(300, 200, 161, 100)
selected_rect = None

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set selected_rect to the colliding rect.
            for rect in (rect1, rect2):
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected_rect = rect
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            selected_rect = None  # De-select.
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected_rect is not None:  # Scale if a rect is selected.
                selected_rect.w += event.rel[0]
                selected_rect.h += event.rel[1]
                selected_rect.w = max(selected_rect.w, 10)
                selected_rect.h = max(selected_rect.h, 10)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 100, 250), rect1)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 200, 120), rect2)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: I wanted to do it for 2 rectangles and it wouldn't work out... I put the code i used in the new edit of my post! Thanks

Comment: After doing so... is it possible to use get_rect() somewhere to get the dimensions of the rectangle, because i plan to make it be able to wrap text within the newly scaled rectangle - Thanks

Comment: You mean like `selected_rect.get_rect()`?

Comment: would ``selected_rect.get_width()`` work to get the width of the rectangle?

Comment: Umm... One last thing. I want to add text inside of the scaling rectangle. Since the rectangle dimensions are always moving, how would I be able to make the text wrap around the scaling rectangle?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiline text with word wrapping and it always needs to fit to the rectangle? Do you use a third party library for the text like [pygame-text](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text)? It's starting to get complicated and I think you should rather ask this in another question with much more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example. You are going to have to adapt it to your situation.

```
import pygame

rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and event.buttons[0]:
            p = event.pos[0] - event.rel[0], event.pos[1] - event.rel[1]
            if pygame.Rect(rect.left, rect.top - 2, rect.width, 4).collidepoint(*p): # top
                rect = pygame.Rect(rect.left, rect.top + event.rel[1], rect.width, rect.height - event.rel[1])
            elif pygame.Rect(rect.left, rect.bottom - 2, rect.width, 4).collidepoint(*p): # bottom
                rect = pygame.Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height + event.rel[1])
            if pygame.Rect(rect.left - 2, rect.top, 4, rect.height).collidepoint(*p): # left
                rect = pygame.Rect(rect.left + event.rel[0], rect.top, rect.width - event.rel[0], rect.height)
            elif pygame.Rect(rect.right - 2, rect.top, 4, rect.height).collidepoint(*p): # right
                rect = pygame.Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width + event.rel[0], rect.height)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```